# C# JSON Data wrongly manipulated after import

Tags: c#, json

Hello (im a noob so please correct me if im using the wrong terms),

I have a problem with a JSON file that im trying to import using StreamReader which looks like the following:

```
    public List<Category> Items;

        try
        {
            using (var r =
                new StreamReader(
                    FilePath1)
            )
            {
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e), "Error");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
```

This exact code worked for me before and the list should hold the following data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elektronik",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "name": "Elektrotechnische Physik",
        "questions": [
          {
            **"question": "Wie ändert sich die Anzahl der freien Elektronen vor und nach dem Schließen eines Stromkreises innerhalb eines Leiters?"**,
            "answer": "Die Anzahl bleibt gleich.",
            "answers": [
              "Die Anzahl verringert sich.",
              "Die Anzahl bleibt gleich.",
              "Die Anzahl erhöht sich.",
              "Es gibt keine freien Elektronen in einem Leiter."
            ]
          }, .....
```

The bold part is the problematic one because the list actually holds the following data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Elektronik",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "name": "Elektrotechnische Physik",
        "questions": [
          {
            **"SubQuestion": null**,
            "answer": "Die Anzahl bleibt gleich.",
            "answers": [
              "Die Anzahl verringert sich.",
              "Die Anzahl bleibt gleich.",
              "Die Anzahl erhöht sich.",
              "Es gibt keine freien Elektronen in einem Leiter."
            ]
          },
```

It deletes all questions and replaces it with "SubQuestion = null". Does anyone know why or know how to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Include your model in your post, it looks to me that the original `question` value isn't being deserialized to an object, thus the serialization sets `SubQuestion` as null because it's a different property. In other words your `SubQuestion` property is missing `[JsonPropertyAttribute("question")]`

Comment: I assume something is miss-configured inside your `Category` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the property name in your json does not match the property name in your model. Your model's likely look like below ... with the exception of Question, which appears to  have a property called "SubQuestion" instead of "question". If that is your intent, as Colin mentioned, you could put a json property on it so that the json can be mapped to the correct property.

```
public class Category
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Subcategory[] subcategories { get; set; }
}

public class Subcategory
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Question[] questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public string[] answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I completly forgot to check that... Thanks!